# Why is this XSL template NOT valid?

Tags: xml, xslt

here is the XML I'm treating:

```
<dsQueryResponse>
<Rows>
<Row ID="14"></Row>
</Rows>
</dsQueryResponse>
```

This XSL is working:

```
    <xsl:template match="Row">
        <xsl:value-of select="@ID"/>
    </xsl:template>
```

But not this one:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="CustomTemplate"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="CustomTemplate">
    <xsl:template match="Row">
        <xsl:value-of select="@ID"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:template>
```

I need to fit with the second structure, making a call-template, does anyone understand what has to be changed in the second XSL ?

Comment: XSL templates cannot be nested.  Please edit your post to show what you want to output given the input XML.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can nest templates like that. What you can do is the following:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:call-template name="CustomTemplate"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="CustomTemplate" match="Row">
  <!-- format rows here -->
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: @Holden - The reason it's not working is because the context is `/` and you're trying to access an attribute in `/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row`. You could use `<xsl:value-of select="dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row/@ID"/>`. Also note that `match="Row"` isn't doing anything right now. You can completely remove the match and it will still work the same.